# Unresolved reference: FlutterTestRunner

Tags: android, flutter, integration-testing

I'm following [Flutter integration test setup for Android](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#android-device-testing) and getting "Unresolved reference: FlutterTestRunner" problem. Cannot figure out how to import it correctly as  `import dev.flutter.plugins.integration_test.FlutterTestRunner` gives "Unresolved reference: dev" error. So how should I import `FlutterTestRunner`?

Also `ActivityTestRule` is deprecated in `androidx.test:rules:1.4.0`. So my additional question would be what is the proper setup for flutter integration testing in Android?

The code from the guide that gives me problems:

```
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import dev.flutter.plugins.integration_test.FlutterTestRunner;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(FlutterTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);
}
```

Comment: To resolve 'Unresolved reference: FlutterTestRunner' please make sure to import `integration_test: sdk: flutter` under `dev_dependencies` in pubspec.yaml and hit `Pub get`

Comment: Also good old File > Invalidate Caches/Restart sometimes helps